# How to get event aggregation to work through Square-Cube REST

Tags: square-cube

Does anyone know how to get event aggregation to work through Square-Cube REST?

Given an event:

```
{
    type: 'sampleType',
    time: '...'
    data:{
        prop: 3.445
    }
}
```

When attempting to sum this, I am getting distinct count by item, rather than sum:

```
http://..:1081/1.0/metric?expression=sum(sampleType(adjClose))

[{"time":"2013-10-16T14:50:50.000Z","value":0},
{"time":"2013-10-16T14:51:00.000Z","value":0},
{"time":"2013-10-16T14:51:10.000Z","value":0},
...,
{"time":"2013-10-16T14:51:40.000Z","value":0},
{"time":"2013-10-16T14:51:50.000Z","value":0}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a step for your summations.  For example:

`http://..:1081/1.0/metric?expression=sum(sampleType(adjClose))&step=36e5`

for every hour,

`http://..:1081/1.0/metric?expression=sum(sampleType(adjClose))&step=864e5`

for every day, and so on.

It is exponential notation for the number of milliseconds you want to sum.

You can also specify a date range.  See [the Cube wiki](https://github.com/square/cube/wiki/Metrics) for a bit more info/examples.